# Android Webview keeps Executing JavaScript even after app closes

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I have a JS script running on loop in a webview and that loops should ideally die when the webview is out of focus or the parent application is closed.

Is there anyway to do this. So far the desired result works on my Google Nexus 7 (4.0) but not on my Kindle (2.2.3)